# Allowing user css

Tags: css, security

I'm allowing user css.

I'm taking their css input, creating a style, and just inserting it.

Are there any security issues I need to consider.

Do I need to validate that css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you do need to be careful, you can take a look at these for more info:

- [Ultimate XSS CSS Injection](http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2007/11/26/ultimate-xss-css-injection/)
- [HTML/CSS Injections - Primitive Malicious Code (or, What’s the worst that could happen?)](http://rgaucher.info/post/2007/02/23/CSS-is-amphetamine-for-your-XSS-Injection)

Comment: Very important as most people don't think CSS as a potential source of an attack. +1up